Inaccessible boot device: working Windows 11 installation fails to boot via USB SATA adapter from the same disk on the same PC
I have just installed Windows 11 on a SATA SSD, updated the system, rebooted multiple times - it works fine. Now I removed this SSD, plugged it into a USB SATA adapter and tried booting from it. The bootloader starts, the Windows 11 logo and spinning indicator appears. But after a bit of spinning (more than normal) with no disk access it shows a blue screen with the "Inaccessible boot device" message.
What could the problem be, and is there a fix / workaround?

@Ramhound: There are no "both disks", it's literally the same disk, only installed internally vs. a USB-SATA adapter. Which software should I view the table with?

So you're thinking it gets a different ID when used through the adapter, so the bootloader refers to a non-existing ID?

Provide the partition table for the disk. A screenshot works best. EFI refers to a specific volume. USB would change the volume id, so providing the BCD also. I won’t answer questions without those screenshots

because in the past I've done this a few times and it always worked that is actually surprising; while changing host bus type does not always break booting in my experience, I don't recall changing from SATA/AHCI to USB/UAS is ever one of those non-breaking cases. Also it is well-known (for more than a decade) that such change is at least very likely to cause "inaccessible boot device" BSOD. (IMO you can really ignore the requests from @Ramhound since none of those information would lead to any difference of capability to provide a solution or a different solution to be provided.)

@TomYan: thanks for confirming this is normal. Probably my memory is wrong and I'm remembering cases when I installed Windows to the USB drive directly, rather than switching after the fact.

The problem is you complete the Windows installation while the SSD was connected by SATA. One way around this is start the installation while the SSD is connected by SATA and then switch to USB before completing the installation. Below are two methods which accomplish this.
The First Method
This method copies the desired Windows 11 image to the SSD while the SSD is connected by SATA. Afterwards, the machine is booted while the SSD is connected by USB. At this point, the hardware is configured so the Windows 11 installation can boot from USB.
The steps are as follows.

Boot from the installer as you did before with SSD connect by SATA. Eventually, a display similar to the one shown below should appear. (This is the first instance of Windows Setup.)


When a display similar to the one shown above occurs, press the key combination shift+F10 to open a Command Prompt window, as shown below.


Enter the command setup /noreboot, as shown below.


The following display should appear. (This is the second instance of Windows Setup.)

Proceed with the installation, until the window shown below appears. (The second instance of Windows Setup has now completed.)


Enter the command exit, as shown below.


The following display should appear. (This is the first instance of Windows Setup.) Select the "Next" button.


Select the "Repair your computer" in the display below.


Select the "Turn off your PC" in the display below.


Put the SSD in the USB SATA adapter, then boot from this drive and proceed with the installation.



The Second Method
This method copies the desired Windows 11 image to the SSD while the SSD is connected by SATA. Afterwards, the machine is boot while the SSD is still connected by SATA. At this point, the hardware is configured so the Windows 11 installation can boot from SATA. To switch to USB booting from the SSD, a process of "Generalization" needs to first take place followed by a shutdown. The SSD can then be switch from SATA to USB. On the next boot, the computer to configure for USB booting from the SSD.
The steps are as follows.

Boot from the installer as you did before with SSD connect by SATA. Proceed until a display similar to the one shown below appears.


Press the key combination control+shift+F3 to reboot to Audit mode, as shown below.


Note: If the System Preparation Tool window does not appear, open the System Preparation Tool, which normally can be found at the location shown below.

C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\sysprep.exe


In the System Preparation Tool window, choose the following, then select the "OK" button. The computer will shut down.


Put the SSD in the USB SATA adapter, then boot from this drive and proceed with the installation.



Update: Fixing your Existing Installation
The OP posted a comment requesting method to fix the existing installation. Below are the steps.

Boot computer with the SSD using a SATA connection.
Note: The data in all user accounts may get deleted. Backup important files.

Open the System Preparation Tool, which normally can be found at the location shown below.
C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\sysprep.exe


Choose the following before selecting the "OK" button.

Wait for the computer to shut down.

Boot the computer with the SSD using a USB connection.

Complete the installation of Windows 11.


References

Windows Setup Command-Line Options
Sysprep (Generalize) a Windows installation


Thank you, but there is no problem with installing Windows to a USB drive, Rufus can unlock that option. I would still like to fix this installation I already have.

I updated by answer with a possible method to fix the installation you already have.

This answer should get more upvotes. Method 1 works. Thank you.
